# Swift How can I keep the lock screen audio controls available after playback paused

Tags: ios, swift, xcode, audio

My app plays audio with a sleep timer. The lock screen audio controls appear correctly and I can use them to pause and play the audio. I can customise the information on the control.

When my sleep timer pauses the audio with self.player.pause() the lock screen controls will stay available for around 10 minutes or so and then disappear. The app is still running and is there when I unlock the iPhone.

Does anyone know of a way to keep the audio control available after I pause playback?

*nb: Because the app is used at night I am trying to reduce user interaction to start the audio. If the user plays audio without a sleep timer it keeps going forever but that uses battery.*

Answer (score 0):

I found the best solution was to enable the controls on the earbuds so that just a click of the centre button restarts playback. This always works.